# netbeans new connection - unable to connect

Tags: sql-server-2008, jdbc, netbeans

I'm trying to connect to sqlserver 2008 r2 database in Netbeans and it keeps giving me this error:

> unable to add connection. Cannot establish connection to jdbc:sqlserver://.... using com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.sqlserverdriver (Java Runtime Environment version 1.8 is not supported by this driver. Use the sqljdbc4.jar class library, which provides support for JDBC 4.0.

This is an existing project that is working just fine and needs a java code update.

I'm using Netbeans 8.1, have java 8 update 73 and java SE kit 8. not sure what else I need to be checking.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by updating the ms sqlserver 2005 driver to point to the sqljdbc4 jar file.  Then it connected fine.